# Problem with function in databricks, it works in python but not in sql

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

[function declare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VxXN.png)

[sample of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26opO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the function as UDF for using it within Spark SQL. Below is the official documentation from Databricks -

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html